# Не меняется контент при переключении табсов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs

Использую радиобаттоны как табсы. При клике на следующую кнопку, должен менятся контент на странице, но этого не происходит. При переключении статично висит контент от первого табса.

```js
var tabsContent = [
  '<div class="row form-group"> <div class="col-12"> <label for="FIO" class="w-100">Укажите вашу фамилию имя отчество:* </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович" id="FIO"> </div> </div> <div class="row "> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label for="regionIndividual">Ваш регион:*</label> <select class="form-control" id="regionIndividual"> <option selected>Выберите регион</option> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> <option>4</option> <option>5</option> </select> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="inputBirthDay">Дата рождения:*</label> <input type="date" placeholder="12.12.1992" class="form-control" id="inputBirthDay"> </div> </div> </div>',

  '  <div class="row form-group"> <div class="col-12"> <label for="businessName" class="w-100">Наименование предприятия:* </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="businessName"> </div> </div> <div class="row "> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label for="regionEnterprises">Ваш регион:*</label> <select class="form-control" id="regionEnterprises"> <option selected>Выберите регион</option> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> <option>4</option> <option>5</option> </select> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="addressEnterprises">Адрес предприятия:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="addressEnterprises"> </div> </div> </div>',

  '<div className="row form-group"> <div className="col-12"> <label htmlFor="enforcementNumber" className="w-100">Номер исполнительного производства:* </label> <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="" id="enforcementNumber"> </div> </div>',
  '   <div class="row form-group "> <div class="col-md-6"> <label for="numberExecutiveDocument" class=""> Номер испол. документа </label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="numberExecutiveDocument"></div><div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="typeExecutiveDocument">Тип исполнительного документа</label><select class="form-control" id="typeExecutiveDocument"><option selected>Выберите тип</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></div></div><div class="row "><div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="regionNumberID">Ваш регион:*</label><select class="form-control" id="regionNumberID"><option selected>Выберите регион</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="executiveDocument">Кто выдал испол. документ (орган)</label><input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="executiveDocument"></div></div></div>'
];



$('.tabs div div input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tabs__content').html(tabsContent[index]);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs div div input[type=radio]:checked').trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="tabs" method="post">
  <div class="row wrapperRadioHome tabs__head">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="individual">
      <label for="individual">
            Физ. лицо
          </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" id="entity" name="tabs">
      <label for="entity">
            Юр. лицо
          </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" id="ipNumber" name="tabs">
      <label for="ipNumber">
            Номер ИП
          </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" id="idNumber" name="tabs">
      <label for="idNumber">
            Номер ИД
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  *****************CHANGE****************  -->
  <div class="tabs__content">

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не там определяете индекс, он один в диве.

```js
var tabsContent = [
  '<div class="row form-group"> <div class="col-12"> <label for="FIO" class="w-100">Укажите вашу фамилию имя отчество:* </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович" id="FIO"> </div> </div> <div class="row "> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label for="regionIndividual">Ваш регион:*</label> <select class="form-control" id="regionIndividual"> <option selected>Выберите регион</option> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> <option>4</option> <option>5</option> </select> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="inputBirthDay">Дата рождения:*</label> <input type="date" placeholder="12.12.1992" class="form-control" id="inputBirthDay"> </div> </div> </div>',

  '  <div class="row form-group"> <div class="col-12"> <label for="businessName" class="w-100">Наименование предприятия:* </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="businessName"> </div> </div> <div class="row "> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label for="regionEnterprises">Ваш регион:*</label> <select class="form-control" id="regionEnterprises"> <option selected>Выберите регион</option> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> <option>4</option> <option>5</option> </select> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="addressEnterprises">Адрес предприятия:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="addressEnterprises"> </div> </div> </div>',

  '<div className="row form-group"> <div className="col-12"> <label htmlFor="enforcementNumber" className="w-100">Номер исполнительного производства:* </label> <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="" id="enforcementNumber"> </div> </div>',
  '   <div class="row form-group "> <div class="col-md-6"> <label for="numberExecutiveDocument" class=""> Номер испол. документа </label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="numberExecutiveDocument"></div><div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="typeExecutiveDocument">Тип исполнительного документа</label><select class="form-control" id="typeExecutiveDocument"><option selected>Выберите тип</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></div></div><div class="row "><div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="regionNumberID">Ваш регион:*</label><select class="form-control" id="regionNumberID"><option selected>Выберите регион</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="executiveDocument">Кто выдал испол. документ (орган)</label><input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" id="executiveDocument"></div></div></div>'
];



$('.tabs div div input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  //console.log($(this).parent().index());

  $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tabs__content').html(tabsContent[index]);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs div div input[type=radio]:checked').trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="tabs" method="post">
  <div class="row wrapperRadioHome tabs__head">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="individual">
      <label for="individual">
            Физ. лицо
          </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" id="entity" name="tabs">
      <label for="entity">
            Юр. лицо
          </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" id="ipNumber" name="tabs">
      <label for="ipNumber">
            Номер ИП
          </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-6 ">
      <input type="radio" id="idNumber" name="tabs">
      <label for="idNumber">
            Номер ИД
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  *****************CHANGE****************  -->
  <div class="tabs__content">

  </div>
</form>
```